# How can I customize my service connection functions?

Tags: customization, webservices

I've got a service connection function where I want to be able to pass the body arguments as a multipart JSON argument, unfortunately the best the standard service connect framework will let me do is pass a `"MultipartData"` argument. Can I hack this in some way?

Answer (score 5):

So after digging through the service connection implementation ( `Lookup[PacletInformation/@PacletFind["*OAuth*"],"Location"]` will find it for you) we find that if we reassign `` ServiceConnections`Private`urlfetchFun[id] `` we can use whatever import function we want. Of course, we won't have the `id` until the [`ServiceObject`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ServiceObject.html) is constructed, but as long as we restrict ourselves to working with our `cookeddata` functions [(see this)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/147196/38205) we should be fine. In each function we'll insert:

```
ServiceConnections`Private`urlfetchFun[id]=
 $serviceconnectionurlfetchfun;
```

before the primary call, where `$serviceconnectionurlfetchfun` is the function we use to import.

That way we can go past a raw `URLFetch`.

The next thing we need to worry about is collecting our `"MulitpartData"` parameters from the `"BodyData"`. Here let's make a function that transfers the parameters, call it `$serviceconnectionreformatmultipartbodydata`.

Right before we call `` <Client_Name>`raw<client_name>data `` in our `cookeddata` function we'll apply this to the `base_call`, `id`, and `params` and it will spit out new `params`. So our `cookeddata` function now looks something like:

```
<service_name>cookeddata[call_name,id_,args___]:=
 Block[{params = Association[args], raw},
  ServiceConnections`Private`urlfetchFun[id]=
   $serviceconnectionurlfetchfun;
  raw =
   processFunction[
    <Client_Name>`raw<client_name>data[
     id, 
     base_call, 
     Normal@
      $serviceconnectionreformatmultipartbodydata[
        base_call,
        id,
        params
        ]
     ]];
  Dataset[raw]
  ]
```

We call it like this so we can take advantage of `` ServiceConnections`Private`getQueryData[id,baseCall] `` from which we can extract which `params` are taken to be part of the `"BodyData"`.

The issue, however, is that our `MultipartData` will be stripped away before the call to `$serviceconnectionurlfetchfun` occurs, but we can get this back by putting a patching parameter (`$serviceconnectionpatchedparameters`) for things we want to make it into the final call in `$serviceconnectionurlfetchfun` and the [`Block`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Block.html) there.

So we have, at the end,

```
<service_name>cookeddata[call_name,id_,args___]:=
 Block[{
  params = Association[args], 
  $serviceconnectionpatchedparameters,
  raw
  },
  ServiceConnections`Private`urlfetchFun[id]=
   $serviceconnectionurlfetchfun;
  raw =
   processFunction[
    <Client_Name>`raw<client_name>data[
     id, 
     base_call, 
     Normal@
      $serviceconnectionreformatmultipartbodydata[
        base_call,
        id,
        params
        ]
     ]];
  Dataset[raw]
  ]
```

And then we have the `$serviceconnectionreformatmultipartbodydata` push its results to `$serviceconnectionpatchedparameters`, which is used by `$serviceconnectionurlfetchfun` to push stuff into the final call that would generally be stripped out.

Here's a brief example of this in action.

I implemented this in my google drive service connection to take care of uploads with metadata.

We start by connecting:

```
$gd = ServiceConnect["GoogleDrive"(*,"New"*)]
```

[image: connection]

And then [google drive uploads](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/create) can take meta-data as well as content data, in which case we use multipart encoding where the metadata is passed as JSON and the content data comes next as raw data.

But I wanted to be able to pass the metadata not as a multipart element, but just as standard arguments to the call, e.g.:

```
$gd["UploadFile",
 "name" -> "test.txt",
 "BodyContent" -> "test string",
 "MIMEType" -> "text/plain",
 "uploadType" -> "multipart"
 ]
```

This isn't the simplest thing to do though, as we have to deal with path and query parameters too. But that's where .The `"BodyContent"` and `"MIMEType"` are fields that define the file content and then anything else in `` ServiceConnections`Private`getQueryData[id,baseCall][[5]] `` (the body data parameters) gets reformatted into metadata.

In the end for this call my patched in `"MultipartData"` looks like:

```
{
 {"metadata","application/json"}->
  ToCharacterCode@ExportString[{"name"->"test.txt"},"JSON"],
 {"contentdata",<"MIMEType">}->
  ToCharacterCode@<"BodyContent">
 }
```

Note that for things like [`File`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/File.html) objects we'll want to pass `ReadString[<"BodyContent">]` instead of the raw content.

But with this in place and the ["Parameters" stripped out](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/147526/38205) it all flows fine:

```
In[23]:= $gd["UploadFile",
 "name" -> "test.txt",
 "BodyContent" -> "test string",
 "MIMEType" -> "text/plain",
 "uploadType" -> "multipart"
 ]//Normal

Out[23]= <|"kind" -> "drive#file", "id" -> "0B3O7g3kj2eCYMzNpWUJmOF9RS28", 
 "name" -> "test.txt", "mimeType" -> "text/plain"|>
```

And then we can delete it with:

```
$gd["DeleteFile",
 "fileId" -> %23["id"]
 ]
```

I took this type of structure (a parameter reformatting `"Pre"` function, a custom `"Fetch"` function -- plus an `"Import"` function to wrap around the call and a `"Post"` function to apply to the dataset) and automated it, so that all I have to supply to my templater is:

```
"UploadFile" -> {
  "Method" -> "POST",
  "Call" -> "RawUploadFile",
  "Post" -> Dataset@*imp@*Normal,
  "Import" -> googledrivepatchedurlfetchblock,
  "Pre" -> googledrivepatchmultipartparams
  }
```

And the `googledrivepatchmultipartparams` patches in the multipart params and `googledrivepatchedurlfetchblock` actually forces `URLFetch` to use the patched in params.

This type of format is a good way to make connecting to services (like Google Drive) that implement more complicated call structures easier.