# Why POST be replaced by GET in HTTP request?

Tags: web-access

I want to use Chinese Word Segmentation and find this API.

sample case work：

```
URLRead[HTTPRequest["api.ltp-cloud.com/analysis/", <|"Query" -> {"api_key" -> "x1e3E1Z3H4AzgRQolEGE8PxHlCEXtTnDbJvkjw5p", 
                    "text" -> "这是一个简单的报文请求", 
                    "pattern" -> "ws", 
                    "format" -> "plain"}, 
                    "Method" -> "GET"|>]["URL"], "Body", CharacterEncoding -> "UTF-8"]
```

> 这 是 一个 简单 的 报文 请求

For adding custom keyworks,we have to build a XML tree.

[image]

the `text` parameter of body is the string object of the XML tree.

I use `Postman` to simulate this process:

```
POST http://api.ltp-cloud.com/analysis/ HTTP/1.1
Host: api.ltp-cloud.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: 6a28f2a0-79f4-af0c-ef5b-23f2c9b03f3f

text=%3Cxml4nlp%3E%3Cnote+lstmsemparser%3D%22n%22+ne%3D%22n%22+parser%3D%22n%22+pos%3D%22n%22+semparser%3D%22n%22+sent%3D%22y%22+srl%3D%22n%22+word%3D%22y%22+%2F%3E%3Cdoc%3E%3Cpara+id%3D%220%22%3E%3Csent+cont%3D%22%E8%87%AA%E5%AE%9A%E4%B9%89%E5%88%86%E8%AF%8D%E7%BB%93%E6%9E%9C%E7%9A%84%E7%A4%BA%E4%BE%8B%22+id%3D%220%22%3E%3Cword+cont%3D%22%E8%87%AA%E5%AE%9A%E4%B9%89%22+id%3D%220%22+%2F%3E%3Cword+cont%3D%22%E5%88%86%E8%AF%8D%22+id%3D%221%22+%2F%3E%3Cword+cont%3D%22%E7%BB%93%E6%9E%9C%22+id%3D%222%22+%2F%3E%3Cword+cont%3D%22%E7%9A%84%22+id%3D%223%22+%2F%3E%3Cword+cont%3D%22%E7%A4%BA%E4%BE%8B%22+id%3D%224%22+%2F%3E%3C%2Fsent%3E%3C%2Fpara%3E%3C%2Fdoc%3E%3C%2Fxml4nlp%3E&api_key=x1e3E1Z3H4AzgRQolEGE8PxHlCEXtTnDbJvkjw5p&pattern=ws&xml_input=true&format=plain
```

[image]

> 自定义 分词 结果 的 示例

I use mma to call this API:

```
xml = Import["https://wolfr.am/nhIeHvVf"];
URLRead[HTTPRequest["api.ltp-cloud.com/analysis/", 
       <|"Body" -> {"api_key" -> "x1e3E1Z3H4AzgRQolEGE8PxHlCEXtTnDbJvkjw5p", 
                    "text" -> xml, 
                    "pattern" -> "ws", 
                    "format" -> "plain", 
                    "xml_input" -> "true"}, 
        "Method" -> "POST", 
        "Headers" -> <|"Content-Type" -> "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"|>|>]["URL"], 
                               "Body", CharacterEncoding -> "UTF-8"]
```

It tells me to input username and password, but this is not necessary.

In `Fiddler`,I find it not sent the body of `HTTPRequest` because it use **`GET`**.
(weird!)

[image]

How to get the same result as Postman?

Comment: I hit a similar snag the other month: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/147526/urlfetch-parameters-interfere-with-post and was able to partially figure it out maybe something there will help

Comment: @b3m2a1 what the method have you used?

Comment: @b3m2a1 and partida, though in this case is appears to be a simple mistake due to `"URL"` in `HTTPRequest[...]["URL"]`.

Comment: I was forced to use `URLFetch` and so something about passing `"Parameters"` to it interfered with the `"Body"` but I hit a similar snag with `HTTPRequest`. What happens if you pre-export your body to a string?

Comment: @Kuba I delete the `["URL"]` and it can works!!! But before,it throwed an error.......

Comment: @partida with URL you drop everything except the url, that is method, body, etc. If you face the earlier problem, let us know.

Comment: @Kuba sure,thank you!