# Execute `sendPhoto` to telegram using telegram-bot api

Tags: web-access

I was create telegram-bot using Mathematica. All the possibilities of telegram api can be found [here](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api). To send images, you can use method [`sendPhoto`](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendphoto). To upload image from hard disk or memory you can use [`multipart/form-data`](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sending-files). But I do not get to send an image this way:

```
data := ExportString[Plot[Sin[x], {x, 1, 3}], "JPEG"]

chatID := $chatID (* allowed chat id *)

token := $token (* https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#authorizing-your-bot *)

body := StringTemplate["
--Asrf456BGe4h
Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"chat_id\"

`chat_id`
--Asrf456BGe4h
Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"photo\";filename=\"photo.jpg\" 
Content-Type: image/jpeg

`data`
--Asrf456BGe4h
"]

length := StringLength[body]

url:=StringTemplate["https://api.telegram.org/bot`token`/sendPhoto"][<|"token"->token|>]

request := HTTPRequest[url, <|
    Method -> "POST", 
    "Headers" -> {"Content-Type" -> "multipart/form-data; boundary=Asrf456BGe4h", 
        "Content-Length" -> ToString@length, 
        "Connection" -> "keep-alive", "Keep-Alive" -> "300"}, 
    "Body" -> body[<|"chat_id" -> chatID, "data" -> data|>]|>]

URLRead[request]

(* Out[..] := HTTPResponse[<|StatusCode -> 504, ...|>] *)
```

How to correctly compose a query to load an image using [`multipart/form-data` (ru)](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multipart/form-data)

Comment: I think the multipart is the core of your problem, so this might help: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/147526/38205

Comment: If you ask this on [**Community**](http://community.wolfram.com) i might be able to attract attention to it and possibly get some answers.